# How to make debug window expressions always stick as watches in PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, watch, pycahrm

I recently updated PyCharm to 2022.2.4 (Professional Edition), and now the debug window looks like so

[image]

Before updating, The debug window had a "+" icon in which I could add a watch expression.
Now, I can type the expression in the top line, but a watch is not added and I have to go all the way to the right and click the + **after** I typed the expression.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question, I found the answer. Thought I'd save someone the hassle by posting anyway:

In the expression line, notice the text

> "Evaluate expression (Enter) or add a watch (Ctrl + Shift + Enter)

So just (Ctrl + Shift + Enter) would create a watch.

[image]